# How do I get and format the contents of a bunch of text files (md5sums) in Linux?

Tags: sed, cat, xargs

I have a bunch of md5 files, which have a hash and a path/filename. I want to output the hash and filename, but not the path.

Example file contents:

```
d7b7494a0602d91b391848dfaebec7ac  /home/develop/md5sums/file1.md5
```

Desired output:

```
d7b7494a0602d91b391848dfaebec7ac file1.md5
dd036a1e1c16b3488309a75f80e5eb92 file2.md5
bf60fb26cbe1f4e9e4001aa485b89ff8 file3.md5
```

My current attempts from searches so far are:

```
cat *.md5 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/\/home\/develop\/md5sums\///g'
```

(Gives an error e.g. for file3.md5: `sed: 2: "bf60fb26cbe1f4e9e4001aa ...": extra characters at the end of d command`)

```
cat *.md5 | xargs -I '{}' sed -i 's/\/home\/develop\/md5sums\////g'
```

(Gives an error e.g. for file3.md5: `sed: -I or -i may not be used with stdin`)

I can probably figure out how to solve it with a `for` loop, but ideally I'd like to keep it as a piped one-liner if possible, and I think there should be a way for `cat`/`xargs`/`sed` to work, I just can't figure it out!

The path is hardcoded, so I don't feel the need to use `basename`, particularly as the md5 file contains more than just the the path/file, which I think makes it more tricky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
sed -E 's:([0-9a-f]+)[[:space:]]+/(.+/)*([^/]+)$:\1 \3:g' file.md5
```

Here we capturing hash, path and last segment of a path and replacing it with hash (`\1`) and last segment (`\3`).

Comment: This was also even better than I had intended as I used the pattern match to trim the filenames as well, stripping the prefixes and suffix

Comment: @BenHolness, I know how this usually happens, so write this way. Though I like simplicity of the other solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed 's: .*/: :' *.md5
```

Output:

```
d7b7494a0602d91b391848dfaebec7ac file1.md5
```

Your attempts didn't work, because you used the `-i` option, which edits the files in-place. But to do that, sed needs to access those files directly. When reading from a piped cat, sed can only see the concatenated contents of the files, it cannot know their location, and therefore can't edit them. That's what the error you got meant. But when we pass the list of files directly to sed, it's able to edit them.

Comment: With that I got an error `sed: 1: "[filename] ...": invalid command code .`

Also note that I do not want to modify the files, I just want to see the formatted version in the output. Perhaps `sed` is the wrong tool for that?

Comment: Oh, then just don't use the `-i` option.

Comment: I also assumed that you have GNU sed, which accepts the `-i` option without an argument, because you used it like that in your attempts. But with other implementations you need something like `-i ""`. Though, in your case that's irrelevant - just remove the option, if you don't want to edit the files.

Comment: Your edit works as well as the other suggestion! Thanks :)